# Retrieve value from object having key and index as a string: 'array[0].key'

Tags: javascript

I'm working with some specific library for forms in javascript. In this library if I have:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "order": 0,
    "title": "A title",
},
```

I can do:

```
const field = 'order';
form.getState().values[field]
```

And I'll get the title value.

Now let's say that I have this data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "order": 0,
    "title": "A title",
    "Tags": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tag one",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Tag two",
        }
    ]
},
```

And also I have access to a string with the name of the field for tags, the index of the array, and the field I want to retrieve. But I have all this in a string:

```
Tags[0].name
```

If I do:

```
const field = 'Tags[0].name';
form.getState().values[field]
```

It will return `undefined`, because will try to find the key `Tags[0].name` in the object. So: how can I do to retrieve the `name` property from a specific index in the `Tags` array, having `Tags[0].name` as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit nasty but quick and working way to do it is to use eval:

```
const field = 'Tags[0].name';
let stateValues = form.getState().values;
let tagName = eval(`stateValues.${ field }`)
```

Other approach might be to split and parse the field path using regexp and then traverse the object property by property.

Comment: Didn't know about `eval`. Clean and clever… Thanks!

Comment: By the way, why nasty?

Comment: @nikita cause eval is 1) slow 2) kills performance

Comment: But in that case I'd say it's not that easy to determine what is faster: a short eval or manual string parsing using not so straightforward regexp.

Comment: After reading about it looks like an overused feature of Javascript time ago. Anyway, probably is justified here.